# Sum of the squares of twelve real numbers which add to $1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

Let $a, b, c,\cdots, l$ be real numbers such that $a + b + c \dots + l = 1.$ Find the minimum value of $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \dots + l^2.$$

My first glance at this problem, I would assume the minimum would be $1,$ gotten by a bunch of zeros, and then a $1.$ I'm not sure if this is correct, and is there a rigorous proof directed toward this?

Comment: Think about interchange symmetry to see that each variable must be the same as the other, so $a = b = \cdots = l = 1/12$.  Then the sum of squares is trivial.

Comment: Did you try setting them all equal?

Comment: Use [AM-QM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities)

Comment: alright, thanks for the advice! I think I got it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimum occurs when $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = \ldots = a_{12} = \frac{1}{12}$, and the minimum such value is $\frac{1}{12}$. To prove this, consider shifting the variables by setting $b_i = a_i - \frac{1}{12}$. We are then trying to minimise
$$\left(b_1 + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 + \left(b_2 + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 + \ldots + \left(b_{12} + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2$$
subject to $b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_{12} = 0$. We then have,
\begin{align*}
&\left(b_1 + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 + \left(b_2 + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 + \ldots + \left(b_{12} + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 \\
= \; &b_1^2 + b_2^2 + \ldots + b_{12}^2 + \frac{1}{6}(b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_{12}) + \frac{1}{12} \\
= \; &b_1^2 + b_2^2 + \ldots + b_{12}^2 + \frac{1}{12}.
\end{align*}
Clearly the above function has a minimum of $\frac{1}{12}$, and is achieved if and only if $b_1 = b_2 = \ldots = b_{12} = 0$ (which satisfies the constraint), i.e. when $a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_{12} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: Very nice argument, +1

Answer (score 2):

$a+b+c+\cdots+l = 1$ is a plane, having $a$-intercept, $b$-intercept, ..., $l$-intercept $1$.  The closest point to the origin is in the $(1,1,1,\cdots,1)$ direction.  The value $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \cdots+ l^2$ is the square of the Euclidean distance of the point $(a,b,c,d,\dots, l)$ from the origin.

As observed, the nearest point on the plane has all coordinates equal and summing to $1$, i.e., $(1/12, 1/12, \cdots, 1/12)$.  The sum of the squares of those coordinates is $1/12$.

Comment: Distance $1$ as observed?

Comment: @ErickWong : "of distance 1 from the origin"

Comment: Seems to me there are a whole circle of points at distance $1$ from the origin.

Comment: @ErickWong : Ack!  That **is** terribly expressed. ...  and then I believed it in the second paragraph.

Comment: @ErickWong : Thanks!  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From AM-QM inequality, we have $a^2+b^2+\cdots+l^2 \geq \frac{1}{12}(a+b+\cdots+l)^2 = \frac{1}{12}$, where the equality holds if and only if $a = b=\cdots =l = \frac{1}{12}$.